# Fetch data from an API while skipping first object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Using react.js, I'm trying to fetch data from an API using the code below:

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';

function App() {
  const [data,setData]=useState([]);
  const getData=()=>{
    fetch('src/data.json')
      .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        setData(myJson)
      });
  }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map((item) =>
        <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and api json response is (sample from data.json):

```
{"users":
  [{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Samantha"}]
}
```

If I remove the object `{"users":` `}` then the code works, but API adds this object to all endpoints.

Is there a way to ignore that first object, or to de-structure it so I get an output of:

- 1 John
- 2 Samantha

Comment: `setData(myJson.users)`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thanks, that seem to work .

Answer (score 0):

If your Javascript interpreter is up to date you can try using the spread operator.

```
object = {"users":
  [{"id":1,"name":"John"},{"id":2,"name":"Samantha"}]
};
object = {...object.users};
```

Result:

```
{ 
  0: {id: 1, name: 'John'},
  1: {id: 2, name: 'Samantha'}
}
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Great suggestion Diego - will also test that - I thankfully have a working version now.  Cheers